# MSSQL: windows -> debian -> windows

Tags: windows, sql-server, debian

Есть mssql-сервер, на который разрешен доступ с debian-сервера.
Нужно каким-то образом присоединиться к нему с windows-клиента.

Возможно ли сделать это с помощью port mapping`a на дебиане? Типа: переброс всех входящих с 1433 порта на mssql-сервер и ответ клиенту.

Или есть какие-то другие готовые решения?

UPD: на windows-клиента IP-адрес динамический

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается, это можно легко сделать с помощью Putty.